# CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER in unit tests causes DetachedInstanceError

Tags: python, unit-testing, celery, python-unittest

I added some celery tasks to my python app, and they work great. I'm trying to fix my test suite for celery as well. I added `celery.conf.CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` to my test suite so that it can run with the tasks executed synchronously.

Problem is that random tests (that do not even use the celery task) are showing the error `DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <MyModel at 0x1096ba690> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'child' cannot proceed`.

Removing `celery.conf.CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True` fixes the problem, but then the celery tasks are sent to the queue but not processed unless I start a worker in the terminal.